# How to add timer in javascript if user select 3 days , timer should be started

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, time, timer

I am making auction app in ReactJS (JavaScript) when add product is filled with time of 3 days after submitting the form , Timer should be started in format hh:mm:ss
I dont have idea to do like this,
what are the best ways for doing this

Comment: Whats wrong in this question as I m getting downvotes ?
I am new in JavaScript thats why want to know about this

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can calculate how much time left in milliseconds, assuming that you receive creation date and days valid from server:

```
const creationDateMS = (new Date(creationDate)).getTime();
const timeLeftMS = (daysValid * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) - (Date.now() - creationDateMS);
```

Then use state to reload the UI. The other way could be using [Moment library](https://momentjs.com/).